# Display wordpress admin bar outside wordpress in Magento?

Tags: admin-bar, magento

I have been trying to get the admin bar to show up under a magento install.  I have tried eveything to get it.  I can get the user, get the footer but nothing happens to get the admin bar up.

from with in a 1column.phtml I called a

```
    <?php 
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('custom/userpanel.phtml')->toHtml(); 
    ?>
```

and in that 'custom/userpanel.phtml' I added :

```
            require_once('/var/www/html/blog/wp-load.php');
            require_once('/var/www/html/blog/wp-blog-header.php');
            require_once('/var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/admin-bar.php');
            require_once('/var/www/html/blog/wp-config.php');

            show_admin_bar(true);
            wp_admin_bar_render();
```

with out anyluck.

I'v tried using

```
            wp_footer();
```

but that doesn't get the bar, and even calling the head function doesn't work

```
            wp_head();
            wp_footer();
```

But althou i get all the head elements like the  and what not which i don't want since it's in the , but still nothing.  What is the way to set it up correctly?

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------

**EDIT**

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------

So I thought I'd get tricky and just grab the admin bar from WP and pull it over almost like jquery .load() but at php runtime.  This is what i did, but here is the odd part, it fails cause it thinks I'm not loged in?

Again in 'custom/userpanel.phtml' of magento which is pull over to WP so when in WP it's all fine but well as of yet nothing here.

```
<div id="wpfoot">
    <?php 


        //wp_head(); 
        if ($userUsername ) {

            if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/') === FALSE ){     

                $dom = new DOMDocument();
                $dom->validateOnParse = true;
                $dom->loadHtml(file_get_contents("http://domain.xxx/blog/"));
                echo $dom->getElementById('wpfoot');

            }else{
                wp_footer();
            }
        }

    // 
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried possible displaying Magento in WordPress? I found an extension that allows Magento blocks within WordPress:
[website](https://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/)

Here is the actual plugin site - [MWI](http://www.mwi-plugin.com/documentation/)

Answer (score 0):

Add also script and styles:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-bar' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-bar' );
```

and `_wp_admin_bar_init()`

You must also include the Hooks for register script and styles or include the scripts from the key 'admin-bar' in your head.

```
/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.js
/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css
```

I think this was all for display the Admin Bar.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
require_once('./wp-load.php');
require_once('./wp-includes/admin-bar.php');
_wp_admin_bar_init();
wp_admin_bar_render();
get_header();
?>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?